# How to count value by type and convert column to row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table "tbTest1" like this:

```
q1 | q2 | q3 | type
---+----+----+-----------
 3 |  2 |  2 | Student
 2 |  2 |  3 | Student
 3 |  1 |  1 | Alumni
 1 |  1 |  3 | Student
 1 |  3 |  2 | Alumni
```

Now I want to convert "tbTest1" into like this where how many 1's,2's or 3's had given by Student for 'q1', 'q2' & 'q3' :

```
q  | 1 | 2 | 3
---+---+---+---
q1 | 1 | 1 | 1
q2 | 1 | 2 | 0
q3 | 0 | 1 | 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select v.q,
       sum(case when val = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as val_1,
       sum(case when val = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as val_2,
       sum(case when val = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as val_3
from tbTest t cross apply
     (values ('q1', t.q1), ('q2', t.q2), ('q3', t.q3)) v(q, val)
where t.type = 'student'
group by v.q;
```

Comment: Now I don't want the sum, I want to count how many 1's, 2's or 3's had given by  student for 'q1', 'q2' and 'q3'

Comment: @NeloySarothi . . . I changed the answer.

Comment: I want one more column 'Aver' average where [(1*x + 2*y + 3*z)/Student Number]  (Example: For 'q1' :-  1*1 + 2*1 + 3*1 = 6/3 =2)

Comment: 'select v.q,
       sum(case when val = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as val_1,
       sum(case when val = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as val_2,
       sum(case when val = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as val_3,
    avg(case when t.userType = 'student' then v.val * 1.0 end) as avg
from tbTest2 t cross apply
     (values ('q1', t.q1), ('q2', t.q2), ('q3', t.q3)) v(q, val)
where t.userType = 'student'
group by v.q;'   I used this sql and it solves my problem. **Thanks for your help**  @Gordon Linoff